# Выбор видео startActivityForResult();

Tags: java, android, видео, android-intent

Можно ли как-то в `startActivityForResult()` вывести откуда я хочу выбрать видео, либо записать с камеры либо выбрать из галереи?
Сейчас только могу открыть окно с записью

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 7);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);
startActivityForResult(intent, VIDEO_CAPTURE);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По идее (из коробки) нельзя, поскольку это разные Intent'ы - для сьемки `MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE`, а для выбора или `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` или `Intent.ACTION_PICK`, ну разве что городить отдельный диалог с их выбором или же полагаться на возможности, которые разные вендоры предлагают, когда во время выбора картинки/видео сразу же можно запросить и съемку.

Но не все так печально. Есть либочка [IntentManip](https://github.com/KingsMentor/IntentManip), которая позволяет объединять несколько разных `Intent`'ов с выбором их из диалога

Comment: Спасибо, отлично подходит для моего проекта))))